# Bootstrap's Togglable Tabs into an accordion at NON desktop size

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

Using Bootstrap's Togglable Tabs I want to display into an accordion if viewed at a smaller screen size (max 768px) - much like the Bootstrap accordion (but doesn't have to have the sliding effect).

```
<div role="tabpanel" id="tabs-test">
              <!-- Nav tabs -->
              <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
              </ul>
              <!-- Tab panes -->
              <div class="tab-content">
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /tabpanel -->
```

**See Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/5685/**

For this to work I need to make the active tab's content show below each according tab.

ie. At the smaller size I need `<div tab-content>` to move to the above `<ul nav-tabs>`, inside of the `<li>` that has a class of active and display only the `<div tab-pane>` that has a class of active. For each active accordion tab the markup should now look something like this-

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>

              <!-- Tab panes -->
              <div class="tab-content">
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
              </div>

    </li>
</ul>
```

I can then use the conditional code below using the window resize function to display it only at the size I need.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
        if ($(this).width() <= 768) {

        }
        else {

        }
    });
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like what you are trying to do is to have a totally different layout for mobile.  It sounds like what you need to use is a Navbar which will become a collapsed menu for mobile.  If you really want to stick with the tabpanel you will have to create a template/view for Desktop, and another for mobile and then swap them out based on width.

Comment: Thank you @Phatjam98 although the Navbar would be suited as a collapsed menu for mobile it doesn't work as tabs for desktop. Can you can send me an example?

Comment: I'll try and put together a quick example in a couple hours.  Is it the look of Tabs you are going for or is there something specific with the Tabs component that you prefer on desktop?  The reason I ask is that you can customize the Navbar to look like tabs if you like.  Generally you can create your own stylesheet which overrides the bootstrap stuff.  This allows you to fine tune and adjust what the bootstrap team gives you out of the box without modifying their styles.

Comment: @Phatjam98 I can customize the look and feel, no worries. Although it is the functionality of the tabs am I after (ie. no page refresh like a navbar would do).

Comment: Ah, gottcha.  I've been working mostly in the realm of "Single Page Applications" for the past couple years.  So you can take the approach of having 2 layouts that you load dynamically with js.  Or you can bundle it all up in one html doc and use media queries to hide/show depending on screen width.  Or you can go a hybrid approach and use the navbar and just use hash navigation, but you'll need to have some JS to back it up.  One suggestion would be to take your sections that you have with tabs, split the html into their own files, and then wire up ajax calls to load and populate as needed.